# Cannot use gcc which is set by autocmd to compile java in MacVim

Tags: java, vim, gcc, javac

I would like to compile my java program using gcc rather than using javac
Because it can give out a more detail information compared to javac.

In my startup configuration.
I use "make" to help me compile my program
so I have to set the compiler for "make" first

I use this command to set the compiler to gcc automatically when the filetype is java.
**autocmd FileType java compiler gcc**

But when I　tried to compile my program using "make"
It give out a lot of message that I don't understand,
and it cannot compile the program.

However, 
When I first set the compiler to javac,then set it to gcc later.
"make" works!!

1. In my startup config : **autocmd FileType java compiler javac**
2. When i am editing the file, **:compiler gcc**

Then I can compile my java program using make with gcc compiler

I don't know what the problem it is.
Can I automatically set compiler to gcc instead of setting it later when editing the file ??

Answer (score 1):

Try `autocmd FileType java set makeprg=gcc` in your .vimrc.

Comment: Thx for your help,
It told me that I miss the gcc compiler for java

But now I find another problem when I use the second setting
.vimrc : autocmd FileType java compiler javac
When i am editing the file, :compiler gcc

I will never use gcc as my compiler
I still use javac as my compiler.
But It give out a more detail information in quick fix list

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I have exactly understood your new problem.

Comment: In my .vimrc right now
I set javac automatically for "make"
But the error messages in quick fix are poor
A single line is for one error

The new problem I discovered is that:
Even I set :compiler gcc when i am editing the file
I never use gcc as my compiler.
The MacVim still use javac to compile my program
But quick fix will show more detailed information
rather than a single line for one error

Thx :)